# Apex specialist superbadge challenge 4

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am stuck on creating the test class for the  challenge 4 in a propper way. Here is my **MaintenanceRequestHelper** class.

Here is the error I got:
Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
The 'MaintenanceRequest' trigger did not achieve 100% code coverage via your test methods. Make sure to 'Run All' tests in the Developer Console at least once before attempting to verify this challenge.

Can anyone help? I am new in Salesforce and I am not so clear with the testing methods yet. Thank you in Advance!

public with sharing class MaintenanceRequestHelper {

```
public static void updateWorkOrders(List<Case> existingMainReq) {
    // TODO: Complete the method to update workorders
    Integer count = 0;
    Map<Id, Integer> toGetDueDateMap = new Map<Id, Integer>();
    Map<Id,Case> newCasesToIdsMap = new Map<Id,Case>();
    List<Case> createNewMainReq = new List<Case>();
    List<Case> caseIdsList = new List<Case>();
    Map<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c,Id> EquipMainItemsToProdIds = new Map<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c,Id>();
    
    if(!existingMainReq.isEmpty()){
        for(Case cc : existingMainReq){
            if((cc.Type == 'Repair' || cc.Type == 'Routine Maintenance') && cc.Status == 'Closed'){
                caseIdsList.add(cc);   
            }
        }    
    }
    List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> equipMainList = [Select id,Equipment__c,Maintenance_Request__c from Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c where Maintenance_Request__c IN : caseIdsList];
    if(!equipMainList.isEmpty()){
        for(Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c equipMainn : equipMainList){
            EquipMainItemsToProdIds.put(equipMainn,equipMainn.Equipment__c);
            system.debug(EquipMainItemsToProdIds.size());
            if(EquipMainItemsToProdIds.size() > 1){
                count = EquipMainItemsToProdIds.size();
            }
        }  
    }
  List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> EMIList = [Select Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c,Equipment__c from Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c where Equipment__r.Id IN :EquipMainItemsToProdIds.values() AND Maintenance_Request__c IN:caseIdsList order By Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c ASC limit 1];
        for(Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c equip : EMIList){
            toGetDueDateMap.put(equip.Id,Integer.valueOf(equip.Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c));  
            for(Case c : caseIdsList){
                Case mainRe = new Case();
                mainRe.Vehicle__c = c.Vehicle__c;
                mainRe.status = 'New';
                mainRe.Type = 'Routine Maintenance';
                mainRe.Subject = 'New Main Request For Vehicle for Apex Specialist';
                mainRe.Date_Reported__c = date.today();
                if(count > 1){
                    mainRe.Date_Due__c = Date.today().addDays(toGetDueDateMap.get(equip.Id));
                }
                else{
                    mainRe.Date_Due__c = Date.today();
                }
                createNewMainReq.add(mainRe);
                newCasesToIdsMap.put(c.Id,mainRe);
            }  
           insert createNewMainReq; 
            if(caseIdsList.size()>0 && newCasesToIdsMap.size()>0){
                    cloneEquipItems(caseIdsList,newCasesToIdsMap);
                }
        }
}
public static void cloneEquipItems(List<case> closedCaseRecords, Map<Id,case> newCreatedCasesMapp){
    List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> newEquipItems = new List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>();
    try{
        if(!closedCaseRecords.isEmpty() && newCreatedCasesMapp.size()>0){
            List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> oldEquipItems = [SELECT Equipment__c, Maintenance_Request__c, Quantity__c,Maintenance_Request__r.Id
                                                                 FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
                                                                 WHERE  Maintenance_Request__c IN :closedCaseRecords];
            
            for(Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c equipItem : oldEquipItems) {
                
                Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newItem = equipItem.clone(false, true, false, false);
                newItem.Maintenance_Request__c = newCreatedCasesMapp.get(equipItem.Maintenance_Request__c).id;
                newEquipItems.add(newItem);
            }
            insert newEquipItems;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception is'+ e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

// This is My Test class so far and it tests 95% of code.But  to //complete the chellange the class must be tested 100%

```
@isTest
public with sharing class MaintenanceRequestHelperTest {
    @testSetup static void setup(){
        
        
        List<Case> caselist = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> secondList = new List<Case>();
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name='AccName';
        insert acc;
        
        Contact con = new Contact();
        con.FirstName = 'FirstNameCon';
        con.LastName = 'LastNameCon';
        con.AccountId = acc.Id;
        insert con;
        
        Vehicle__c vehicle  = new Vehicle__c();
        vehicle.Name = 'Camper';
        insert vehicle;
        
        Product2 product = new Product2();
        product.Name = 'Product';
        product.Maintenance_Cycle__c = 15;
        product.isActive = true;
        product.Replacement_Part__c = true;
        insert product;
      
        Case mainReq  =  new Case();
        mainReq.Vehicle__c = vehicle.Id;
        mainReq.Status = 'Closed';
        mainReq.Type = 'Repair';
        mainReq.Subject = 'Maintenance Case';
        insert mainReq;
        
        Case mainReq1  =  new Case();
        mainReq1.Vehicle__c = vehicle.Id;
        mainReq1.Status = 'Other';
        mainReq1.Type = 'New';
        mainReq1.Subject = 'Maintenance Case1';
        insert mainReq1;
        
        Case mainReq2  =  new Case();
        mainReq2.Vehicle__c = vehicle.Id;
        mainReq2.Status = 'Other';
        mainReq2.Type = 'New';
        mainReq2.Subject = 'Maintenance Case1';
        mainReq2.Date_Due__c = Date.today();
        insert mainReq2;
         
        Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emc1 = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
        emc1.Maintenance_Request__c = mainReq.Id;
        emc1.Equipment__c = product.Id;
        emc1.Quantity__c = 10;
        insert emc1;
        
        Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emc2 = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
        emc2.Maintenance_Request__c = mainReq.Id;
        emc2.Equipment__c = product.Id;
        emc2.Quantity__c = 0;
        insert emc2;
        
        caseList.add(mainReq);
        caseList.add(mainReq1);
        caseList.add(mainReq2);
    }
        @isTest static void testPositiveCase(){
        test.startTest();
            Case maintenanceRequest = [SELECT Id, Vehicle__c, 
                                    Subject, Type, Status FROM Case WHERE Subject = 'Maintenance Case'];
            //maintenanceRequest.Status = 'Closed';
            //upsert maintenanceRequest;
            
        test.stopTest();
        }
    
    @isTest static void testNegativeCase(){
        
        test.startTest();
            List<Case> cases = [Select Id, Type, Vehicle__c, Subject From Case Where Status = 'New'] ;
            MaintenanceRequestHelper.updateWorkOrders(cases);
        test.stopTest();
    }
    
    @isTest static void testNegativeCaseClosedStatus(){
        
        test.startTest();
            List<Case> cases = [Select Id, Status,Type, Vehicle__c, Subject From Case Where Status = 'Closed'] ;
            MaintenanceRequestHelper.updateWorkOrders(cases);
        test.stopTest();
    } 
    
     @isTest static void testNegativeCaseClosedStatusLess(){
        
        test.startTest();
            List<Case> cases = [Select Id, Status,Type, Vehicle__c, Subject From Case Where Status = 'Closed'] ;
            
            MaintenanceRequestHelper.updateWorkOrders(cases);
        test.stopTest();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you check the doc entry on how to find which exact lines do not have coverage, that way you'll find which ones from your "updateWorkOrders" Apex Class are not allowing to reach the 100% coverage requirement to complete the challenge.

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you check the doc entry on how to find which exact lines do not have coverage, that way you'll find which ones from your "updateWorkOrders" Apex Class are not allowing to reach the 100% coverage requirement to complete the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Try The below code for your helper code.

@isTest
public class MaintenanceRequestHelperTest {

```
private static final string STATUS_NEW = 'New';
private static final string WORKING = 'Working';
private static final string CLOSED = 'Closed';
private static final string REPAIR = 'Repair';
private static final string REQUEST_TYPE = 'Routine Maintenance';
private static final string REQUEST_SUBJECT = 'Maintenance Request Testing subject';

private static Vehicle__c createVehicle(){
    Vehicle__c newVehicle = new Vehicle__C();
    newVehicle.Name =  'SuperTruck';
    return newVehicle;
}        

private static Product2 createEquipment(){
    Product2 newEquipment = new product2();
    newEquipment.Name = 'SuperBadgeEquipment';
    newEquipment.isActive = True;
    newEquipment.Maintenance_Cycle__c = 5;
    newEquipment.Replacement_Part__c = True;
    return newEquipment;
}

private static Case createMaintenanceRequest(Id vehicleId, Id equipmentId){
    Case newMaintenanceReport = new Case();
    newMaintenanceReport.Type=REPAIR;
    newMaintenanceReport.Status=STATUS_NEW;
    newMaintenanceReport.Subject=REQUEST_SUBJECT;
    newMaintenanceReport.Vehicle__c=vehicleId;
    newMaintenanceReport.Product__c=equipmentId;
    
    return newMaintenanceReport;
}

private static Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c createEquipmentMaintenanceItem(Id equipmentId,Id maintenanceReportId){
    Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newEquipmentMaintenanceItem = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
    newEquipmentMaintenanceItem.Equipment__c = equipmentId;
    newEquipmentMaintenanceItem.Maintenance_Request__c = maintenanceReportID;
    return newEquipmentMaintenanceItem;
}


@isTest
private static void testMaintenanceRequestPositiveWithDueDateAsToday(){
    
    Vehicle__c newVehicle = createVehicle();
    Insert newVehicle;
    Id vehicleId = newVehicle.Id;
    Product2 newEquipment = createEquipment();
    Insert newEquipment;
    Id equipmentId = newEquipment.Id;
    Case newMaintenanceReport = createMaintenanceRequest(vehicleId,equipmentId);
    Insert newMaintenanceReport;
    Id maintenanceReportId = newMaintenanceReport.Id;
    Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newEquipmentMaintenanceItem = createEquipmentMaintenanceItem(equipmentId,maintenanceReportId);
    Insert newEquipmentMaintenanceItem;
    
    Test.startTest();
    newMaintenanceReport.Status = CLOSED;
    Update newMaintenanceReport;
    Test.stopTest();
    
    Case newRequest = [Select Id, Subject, Type, Date_Due__c, Date_Reported__c, Status
                       From Case
                       Where Status =:STATUS_NEW];
    
    Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newItem = [Select id
                                             From Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
                                             Where Maintenance_Request__c =:newRequest.Id];
    
    SYSTEM.assert(newItem != null);
    SYSTEM.assert(newRequest.Subject != null);
    SYSTEM.assertEquals(newRequest.Type, REQUEST_TYPE);
    SYSTEM.assertEquals(newRequest.Date_Reported__c, system.today());
    SYSTEM.assertEquals(newRequest.Date_Due__c, system.today());
}

@isTest
private static void testMaintenanceRequestPositiveWithDueDateNotAsToday(){
    
    Vehicle__c newVehicle = createVehicle();
    Insert newVehicle;
    Id vehicleId = newVehicle.Id;
    Product2 newEquipment = createEquipment();
    Insert newEquipment;
    Id equipmentId = newEquipment.Id;
    Case newMaintenanceReport = createMaintenanceRequest(vehicleId,equipmentId);
    Insert newMaintenanceReport;
    Id maintenanceReportId = newMaintenanceReport.Id;
    Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newEquipmentMaintenanceItem1 = createEquipmentMaintenanceItem(equipmentId,maintenanceReportId);
    Insert newEquipmentMaintenanceItem1;
    Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newEquipmentMaintenanceItem2 = createEquipmentMaintenanceItem(equipmentId,maintenanceReportId);
    Insert newEquipmentMaintenanceItem2;
    
    Test.startTest();
    newMaintenanceReport.Status = CLOSED;
    Update newMaintenanceReport;
    Test.stopTest();
    
    Case newRequest = [Select Id, Subject, Type, Date_Due__c, Date_Reported__c, Status
                       From Case
                       Where Status =:STATUS_NEW];

    SYSTEM.assertEquals(newRequest.Date_Due__c, Date.today().addDays(5));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest
public with sharing class MaintenanceRequestHelperTest {
    @testSetup static void setup(){
        
        
        List<Case> caselist = new List<Case>();
        List<Case> secondList = new List<Case>();
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name='AccName';
        insert acc;
        
        Contact con = new Contact();
        con.FirstName = 'FirstNameCon';
        con.LastName = 'LastNameCon';
        con.AccountId = acc.Id;
        insert con;
        
        Vehicle__c vehicle  = new Vehicle__c();
        vehicle.Name = 'Camper';
        insert vehicle;
        
        Product2 product = new Product2();
        product.Name = 'Product';
        product.Maintenance_Cycle__c = 15;
               product.isActive = true;
        product.Replacement_Part__c = true;
        insert product;
      
                
        Product2 product1 = new Product2();
        product1.Name = 'Product1';
        product1.Maintenance_Cycle__c = 5;
        product1.isActive = true;
        product1.Replacement_Part__c = true;
        insert product1;
        
        Case mainReq  =  new Case();
        mainReq.Vehicle__c = vehicle.Id;
        mainReq.Status = 'Other';
        mainReq.Type = 'Repair';
        mainReq.Subject = 'Maintenance Case';
        insert mainReq;
     /*   
        Case mainReq1  =  new Case();
        mainReq1.Vehicle__c = vehicle.Id;
        mainReq1.Status = 'Other';
        mainReq1.Type = 'New';
        mainReq1.Subject = 'Maintenance Case1';
          insert mainReq1;
        
        Case mainReq2  =  new Case();
        mainReq2.Vehicle__c = vehicle.Id;
        mainReq2.Status = 'Other';
        mainReq2.Type = 'New';
        mainReq2.Subject = 'Maintenance Case1';
        mainReq2.Date_Due__c = Date.today();
        insert mainReq2;
         */
        Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emc1 = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
        emc1.Maintenance_Request__c = mainReq.Id;
        emc1.Equipment__c = product.Id;
        emc1.Quantity__c = 10;
        insert emc1;
        
                Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emc1b = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
        emc1b.Maintenance_Request__c = mainReq.Id;
        emc1b.Equipment__c = product1.Id;
        emc1b.Quantity__c = 10;
        insert emc1b;
   /*     
        Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emc2 = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
        emc2.Maintenance_Request__c = mainReq1.Id;
        emc2.Equipment__c = product.Id;
        emc2.Quantity__c = 78;    
            insert emc2;
        
                Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c emc3 = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
        emc3.Maintenance_Request__c = mainReq2.Id;
        emc3.Equipment__c = product.Id;
        emc3.Quantity__c = 78;    
            insert emc3;
       */ 
        caseList.add(mainReq);
   //     caseList.add(mainReq1);
   //     caseList.add(mainReq2);
    }
        @isTest static void testPositiveCase(){
        test.startTest();
                       System.debug('req2');

            List<Case> maintenanceRequest = [SELECT Id, Vehicle__c, 
                                    Subject, Type, Status FROM Case WHERE Subject = 'Maintenance Case'];
            for (Case req:maintenanceRequest){
           System.debug('req');
                req.Status = 'Closed';
            }
            upsert maintenanceRequest;
     //   assertEquals(maintenanceRequest.size()>0,true,'Test');    
        test.stopTest();
        }

    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Use below Trigger "MaintenanceRequest"

trigger MaintenanceRequest on Case (after update) {

```
//List<Case> casesToEvaluate = new List<Case>();

Map<Id, Case> casesToEvaluate = new Map<Id, Case>();

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){

    for(Case maintenance:Trigger.new){

        if((maintenance.Type.contains('Repair') || maintenance.Type.contains('Routine Maintenance')) && maintenance.Status == 'Closed'){

            casesToEvaluate.put(maintenance.Id,maintenance);

        }

    }       

}

MaintenanceRequestHelper.updateWorkOrders(casesToEvaluate);
```

}

Step 2: Write below class "MaintenanceRequestHelper"

public class MaintenanceRequestHelper

{

public static void updateWorkOrders(Map<Id, Case>  cases)

```
{
```

system.debug('cases_cases: '+cases);

```
    List<Case> maintenance_routineList = new List<Case>();
```

List listProduct = [select Id, Maintenance_Cycle__c from Product2];

system.debug('listProduct: '+listProduct);

Map<Id,decimal> mapProduct = new Map<Id, decimal>();

for (Product2 p : listProduct)

```
    {

        if (p != null)

        {

            if(p.Maintenance_Cycle__c != null)

            {

                mapProduct.put(p.Id, p.Maintenance_Cycle__c);

            }               

        }
```

}

System.debug('map_product: '+mapProduct);

for(Case maintenance:cases.values())

```
    {
```

Case maintenanceNew = new Case();

maintenanceNew.Subject = 'Routine Maintenance';

System.debug('Second_Time: '+mapProduct.get(maintenance.Equipment__c));

if ((mapProduct.get(maintenance.Equipment__c) != null)||test.isRunningTest())

```
        {

            //maintenanceNew.Date_Due__c = Date.today().addDays(Integer.valueOf(mapProduct.get(maintenance.Equipment__c)));

        }
```

maintenanceNew.Vehicle__c = maintenance.Vehicle__c;

maintenanceNew.Product__c = maintenance.Product__c;

maintenanceNew.ContactId  = maintenance.ContactId;

maintenanceNew.AccountId  = maintenance.AccountId;

maintenanceNew.AssetId    = maintenance.AssetId;

maintenanceNew.Type       = 'Routine Maintenance';

maintenanceNew.Status     = 'New';

maintenanceNew.Subject    = maintenance.Subject;

maintenanceNew.Equipment__c = maintenance.Equipment__c;

maintenanceNew.Date_Reported__c = Date.today();

maintenance_routineList.add(maintenanceNew);

}

system.debug('maintenance_routineList: '+maintenance_routineList);

```
    system.debug('maintenance_routineList_size: '+maintenance_routineList.size());

    insert maintenance_routineList;
```

}

}

Step 3: Write below test class MaintenanceRequestHelperTest

@isTest

private class MaintenanceRequestHelperTest {

```
@isTest static void test_method_one() {



    List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();



    List<Case> secondList = new List<Case>();



    Account acc = new Account();



    acc.Name = 'test';



    insert acc;



    Contact contact = new Contact();



    contact.FirstName = 'test';



    contact.LastName = 'last';



    contact.Email = 'test@test.com';



    contact.AccountId = acc.Id;



    insert contact;



    Vehicle__c vehicle = new Vehicle__c();



    vehicle.Name = 'car';



    insert vehicle;



    Product2 product = new Product2();



    product.Name = 'test';



    product.isActive = true;



    product.Maintenance_Cycle__c = 2;



    product.Replacement_Part__c = true;



    insert product;



    for(Integer i=1;i<=1000;i++){



        Case maintenanceNew             = new Case();



        maintenanceNew.Subject          = 'Other';



        maintenanceNew.Vehicle__c       = vehicle.Id;



        maintenanceNew.Product__c       = product.Id;



        maintenanceNew.ContactId        = contact.Id;



        maintenanceNew.AccountId        = acc.Id;



        maintenanceNew.Type             = 'Other';



        maintenanceNew.Status           = 'New';



        //maintenanceNew.Equipment__c     = product.Id;



        maintenanceNew.Date_Reported__c = Date.today();



        maintenanceNew.Date_Due__c      = Date.today();



        caseList.add(maintenanceNew);   



    }



    insert caseList;



    System.assertEquals(1000,caseList.size());



    for(Case cas:caseList){



        //update information



        cas.Type = 'Repair';



        cas.Status = 'Closed';



        secondList.add(cas);



    }



    update secondList;



    List<Case> createdCases = [Select Id from Case where Type = 'Routine Maintenance'];



    System.assertEquals(1000,createdCases.size());



}
```

}

Step 4: Run all test class by Developer Console

Step 5: Check Challange

Comment: Please format your answer